# does MongoDB's getLastError() command indicate the number of records affected by a $rename command?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I'm developing an application that preens imported data using field maps in a "dictionary" collection, and am trying to see how many records were affected by a [`$rename`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/rename/) operation.  When does the mongo shell call [`db.getLastError()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getLastError/) on behalf of the user?  I've read that it does call `getLastError()` before accepting new statements interactively in the console, but what are the semantics for command-line invocations like `mongo script.js`?  I'm assuming `getLastError()` is not called at all for scripts, but haven't been able to find confirmation in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Opening New Connections doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#opening-new-connections):

> ... Additionally, inside the script, you would need to call
>   db.getLastErrorObj() or db.getLastError() explicitly to wait for the
>   result of write operations.

The `db.getLastErrorObj()` is what you want to call to get the result of the update/$rename operation.  It returns and object that looks like:

```
{
    "updatedExisting" : true,
    "n" : 2,
    "connectionId" : 35,
    "err" : null,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

`n` is the number of updated documents.

Comment: thanks, @mjhm - looks like i didn't research enough.  i'll review that documentation and refactor my style.